# SFML multi-touch events not designed for magic trackpad?

Tags: macos, touch, sfml

I am trying get touch/multi-touch events in SFML in Mac, and I am not receiving any.  Some research yields that touch was designed for Android and iOS devices (perhaps any device with touch screen?)

Is there a way to get touch events in SFML from the Mac's trackpad?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

They are currently (SFML 2.3) not supported.